# How to find a language L that is equal to L*??

Tags: automata, formal-languages, regular-language, finite-automata

I have a problem and I don't understand it.
I need to find a **language $L$** (using the alphabet $\Sigma = \{a,b\}$)
The problem is that $L$ can't be $\{a,b\}^*$ or $\{\epsilon\}$ and it must be equal to $L^*$.
Any ideas?
Sorry if my english is not good.

Comment: Hint: what set is represented by $X^{**}$, for any set $X$?

Comment: I don't know, is it about Kleene Star?

Answer (score 0):

How about defining $L=\{\epsilon, a, aa, aaa, aaaa, \ldots\}$?  This is the set of all strings made only of the letter $a$.

The Kleene star language $L^*$ consists of any number of strings from $L$ concatenated together. But if you concatenate any strings made of only $a$ characters together, the result will also be a string made of $a$ characters. Hence $L=L^*$.